# How to change Bootstrap daterangepicker language in the sidebar's selector

Tags: daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Im trying to change the language to Spanish using the locale property. This works fine, but I can only find the properties to translate only some of the strings.

As you can see in the image below, the months and weekdays are translated into Spanish, but **the sidebar is not**.

Is there any property to change these values?

[image: Calendar]

Locale property:

```
"locale": {
        "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
        "fromLabel": "Desde",
        "toLabel": "Hasta",
        "customRangeLabel": "Personalizado",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Lu",
            "Ma",
            "Mi",
            "Ju",
            "Vi",
            "Sá",
            "Do"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "Enero",
            "Febrero",
            "Marzo",
            "Abril",
            "Mayo",
            "Junio",
            "Julio",
            "Agusto",
            "Septiembre",
            "Octubre",
            "Noviembre",
            "Diciembre"
        ],
        "firstDay": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be late to the game, but the ranges on the left are not defined in the locale.

They are part of the parameters handed in `ranges`

```
  ranges: {
          'Heute': [moment(), moment()],
          'Gestern': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
          'Aktueller Monat': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
          'Letzter Monat': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
          'Januar 2019': [moment([2019,0]), moment(moment([2019,0]).endOf('month')) ],
          '1. Quartal 2019': [moment().quarter(1).startOf('quarter'), moment().quarter(1).endOf('quarter')],
          '2. Quartal 2019': [moment().quarter(2).startOf('quarter'), moment().quarter(2).endOf('quarter')],
          '3. Quartal 2019': [moment().quarter(3).startOf('quarter'), moment().quarter(3).endOf('quarter')],
          '4. Quartal 2019': [moment().quarter(4).startOf('quarter'), moment().quarter(4).endOf('quarter')]
        },
```

BTW: I answered to your question not only but mostly because I was looking for exactly what you pasted in your question. So thanks for asking ;-)